# Responsive table - Replacing Table with Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I currently creating my own responsive table. I am nearly there especially with a little help from [Manji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166538/manji). What I need to do now is to append or replace the divs below the table when the browser is below 996px width. So far I have got this

```
$(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {

        var width = $(window).width();

        if (width <= 996){
            $(table).replaceWith(output);
        } else {
            //bring it back
        }
    });
```

It works when you make your browser window smaller, but obvis. doesnt go back to normal when you resize.

You can look at the [DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HBjAb).

My question is, how can I get this to work correctly, and is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why the hell are you trying to make a responsive table?

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste How is that question valid?

Comment: If it's a data table, just let the browser do its job!
If it's not a data table, then it should not be a table...
That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this is to build the content up-front and not on-the-fly. Using your approach of using jQuery to render the content, we'd modify it as follows:

First, we need to set the 'mobile' table to have the right style (in this case, no display):

```
output += '<div class="mobiled-table" style="display: none">';
```

The rest of your DOM build proceeds as usual, but we render it immediately once we've finished writing it:

```
output += '</div>';
var mobile_table = $(output);
$(table).after(mobile_table);
```

Now your event is free to hide/show as we're rendering:

```
$(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 996) {
        mobile_table.show();
        table.hide();
    } else {
        mobile_table.hide();
        table.show();
    }
});
```

This means that when the actual event happens, very large tables will not incur the DOM build time (which can be significant on large tables). It also means that you can push the DOM building out of jQuery (which is not really suited for it, but as you saw can do it by concatenation -- just beware when the database has less-than or greater-than signs etc. in it) and you can instead render the mobile table with the same code that renders the non-mobile table.

Furthermore you can then, as Joe Frambach indicated, move this stuff completely out of jQuery and into CSS, where it will be faster and clearer:

```
.mobiled-table { display: none }
@media (max-width: 996px) {
    table { display: none }
    .mobiled-table { display: block !important }
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely spot on. Thank you Chris :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in pure css. It won't be pretty but you can do it.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  table, thead, tbody, th, tr, td {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

And that's it!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qFDvr

Comment: Your responsive table looks completely different to mine if you use this method.

Answer (score -1):

There's an online tool which lets you convert your tables to structured div elements with just a few clicks: [www.html-cleaner.com](http://www.html-cleaner.com)

Read more about this feature and find the css code you have to use here: http://www.html-cleaner.com/features/replace-html-table-tags-with-divs/